# What content should be preloaded and how?

Tags: javascript, html, pagespeed, preload

I just learned about [`rel="preload"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content) and I wonder when it should be used. I found different types of preloads like [preloading with javascript etc.](https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/) as well. Google recently [announced](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2018/01/using-page-speed-in-mobile-search.html) it would rank faster loading pages higher (at least on mobile) making pagespeed even more important for everyone.

If you already use HTTP/2 (HTTP/2.0), HTTPS, gzip, CDNs etc. and want to have your sites load as fast as possible: **Should you** (additionally) **use preloads** and in what quantity **?**

Should you add [HTML5 `rel="preload"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content) to every link, script, font etc. or just some of them? Maybe only to external ones?

Or is it better to rely on javascript and its libraries to preload resources?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but not really a good fit for SO. The answer, as with so many questions like this is: it depends. Going into what it depends on could literally fill a book.

Comment: @JaredSmith So there isn't some general thumb rule  you can go with for small to medium size websites?

Comment: Yes, and that rule of thumb is: "don't bother". Seriously. You are spending time optimizing things that almost certainly don't matter instead of adding features. Set yourself a peformance budget (e.g. < 1s to first meaningful paint, < 5s to full interactivity on 3G connected mid-tier mobile device). Start with simplest thing (bundle all js files, un-optimized images, no special add-ons like mod-pagespeed). Then add optimizations from simple to complex until you are within your budget. You're waaay lost in the weeds man. Never ever optimize without clear metrics.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm still a student so I value insights like this a lot. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I think most of us go there at some point in our career:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend preloading resources that you have high-confidence will be used in the current page. Preload is an early fetch instruction to the browser to request a resource needed for a page, and it is worth fetching things like key scripts, Web Fonts, and hero images (the things that could block the browser rendering).

This article does a fantastic job of explaining the ins and outs of preload and prefetch and when you should use them:

https://medium.com/reloading/preload-prefetch-and-priorities-in-chrome-776165961bbf